# unix socket datagram: server receive invalid characters

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to create a Unix socket datagram example. The client can send and receive message smoothly. The server is able to do that just in case the buffer length is smaller than `SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE`, otherwise the server's output shows some invalid characters at received buffer.

Client's code

```c
#include "ud_hdr.h"

#define IN_BUF_SIZE     200

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_un  svr_addr, cli_addr;
    int                 sfd, i;
    ssize_t             num_rw;
    socklen_t           svr_addr_len;
    char                sock_buf[SOCK_BUF_SIZE];
    char                in_buf[IN_BUF_SIZE];

    // Create sockets:
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1) {
        printf("Error line|%d|: %s", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // ! In Unix domain, the client needs to assign an address to its socket
    // ! if it wants to RECEIVE datagrams sent by server.
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    cli_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    snprintf(cli_addr.sun_path, sizeof(cli_addr.sun_path), \
            "/tmp/dxduc/ud_cli.%ld", (long)getpid());
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1) {
        printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Construct server's address:
    memset(&svr_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svr_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svr_addr.sun_path, SOCKET_SV_PATH, sizeof(svr_addr.sun_path) - 1);

    printf("Client is ready to run\n");
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter new msg: ");
        fflush(stdout); // * clear the output buffer and move the buffered data to output (a.k.a console in this case)
        memset(in_buf, 0, sizeof(in_buf));
        memset(sock_buf, 0, sizeof(sock_buf));
        num_rw = read(STDIN_FILENO, in_buf, IN_BUF_SIZE);

        // Remove '\n' and '\r' in input:
        for (i = 0; i < IN_BUF_SIZE; i++) {
            // if ((in_buf[i] == '\r') || (in_buf[i] == '\n')) {
            if (in_buf[i] == '\n') {
                in_buf[i] = 0x0;
            }
        }

        printf("Msg to server: |%s|, len = %ld, num_rw = %ld\n", in_buf, strlen(in_buf), num_rw);
        svr_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
        if (num_rw > 0) {
            // Send msg to server:
            if (sendto(sfd, in_buf, strlen(in_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, svr_addr_len) != strlen(in_buf)) {
                printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        } else if (num_rw == 0) {
            printf("Nothing to send to server\n");
            continue;
        } else if (num_rw == -1) {
            printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Read response from server
        num_rw = recvfrom(sfd, sock_buf, SOCK_BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, &svr_addr_len);
        if (num_rw == -1) {
            printf("Error line|%d|, %s", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            printf("Receive from server: |%s|, len=%ld, num_rw=%ld\n", sock_buf, strlen(sock_buf), num_rw);
        }
    }
}
```

Server's code

```c
#include "ud_hdr.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_un  svr_addr, cli_addr;
    int                 sfd, i;
    ssize_t             num_rw;
    socklen_t           cli_addr_len;
    char                buf[SOCK_BUF_SIZE];

    // Create socket:
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1) {
        printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Verify socket's name path:
    if (strlen(SOCKET_SV_PATH) > (sizeof(svr_addr.sun_path) - 1)) {
        printf("Error line|%d|: invalid socket name", __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Remove any existing file having the same namepath with server's:
    if ((remove(SOCKET_SV_PATH) == -1) && (errno != ENOENT)) {
        printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind the socket to desired addr:
    memset(&svr_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svr_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svr_addr.sun_path, SOCKET_SV_PATH, sizeof(svr_addr.sun_path) - 1);

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&svr_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1) {
        printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1) {
        // Receive data from client:
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        cli_addr_len = sizeof (struct sockaddr_un);
        num_rw = recvfrom(sfd, buf, SOCK_BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &cli_addr_len);

        if (num_rw == -1) {
            printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Server received %ld bytes from %s, ret_buf=|%s|, len=%ld\n", (long)num_rw, cli_addr.sun_path, buf, strlen(buf));

        // Uppercase received characters:
        for (i = 0; i < num_rw; i++) {
            buf[i] = toupper((unsigned char)buf[i]);
        }

        // Send back uppercase-ed characters to client:
        printf("Send back to client: |%s|, len=%ld\n", buf, strlen(buf));
        if (sendto(sfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, cli_addr_len) != strlen(buf)) {
            printf("Error line|%d|: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Header file

```c
#ifndef _UD_HDR_H_
#define _UD_HDR_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// * The Makefile should have created /tmp/dxduc before run this program
#define SOCKET_SV_PATH      "/tmp/dxduc/ud_basic"
#define SOCK_BUF_SIZE            10

#endif // _UD_HDR_H_
```

This is what I got

```console
# Client
Client is ready to run
Enter new msg: stack  
Msg to server: |stack|, len = 5, num_rw = 6
Receive from server: |STACK|, len=5, num_rw=5
Enter new msg: stackoverflow
Msg to server: |stackoverflow|, len = 13, num_rw = 14
Receive from server: |STACKOVERF|, len=10, num_rw=10

#Server
Server received 5 bytes from /tmp/dxduc/ud_cli.2385, ret_buf=|stack|, len=5
Send back to client: |STACK|, len=5
Server received 10 bytes from /tmp/dxduc/ud_cli.2385, ret_buf=|stackoverf�  |, len=14
Send back to client: |STACKOVERF�   |, len=14
```

It's weird that the client received the expected message, though the server did not format the message correctly before sending it.

This is my expected output

```console
# Client
Client is ready to run
Enter new msg: stack  
Msg to server: |stack|, len = 5, num_rw = 6
Receive from server: |STACK|, len=5, num_rw=5
Enter new msg: stackoverflow
Msg to server: |stackoverflow|, len = 13, num_rw = 14
Receive from server: |STACKOVERF|, len=10, num_rw=10

#Server
Server received 5 bytes from /tmp/dxduc/ud_cli.2385, ret_buf=|stack|, len=5
Send back to client: |STACK|, len=5
Server received 10 bytes from /tmp/dxduc/ud_cli.2385, ret_buf=|stackoverf|, len=10
Send back to client: |STACKOVERF|, len=14
```

How should I solve it?

Comment: it is possible that your buffer is not zero terminated

Comment: @dvhh which buffer are you mentioning? The buffer that client prepares to send to server?

Comment: @dvhh There's no "possible" about it.  `sendto(sfd, in_buf, strlen(in_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, svr_addr_len)` will not send a proper C string as it will ***not*** be zero-terminated.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I understood how to fix this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `SOCK_BUF_SIZE` is 10 and you receive 10 bytes (in your client). It overwrites your 0 byte.
You should use

```
char sock_buf[SOCK_BUF_SIZE+1];
```